# Find if value greater than a number exists in comma separated string in MySql Column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table with values given below

```
payment_pattern application
0,0,117,9,5  XXXX0004DqjBQAS
0,30,0,29,16,0   XXX000004E79tQAC
30,30,23,29,22,1 XXX000006F2brQAC
0,0,0,0,29,28    XXXB000006Fs3oQAC
```

Need to find regular expression that would return all rows with values greater than or equal to 30.

Example output should be

```
0,0,117,9,5 XXXX0004DqjBQAS
0,30,0,29,16,0  XXXX0004E79tQAC
30,30,23,29,22,1 XXXX0006F2brQAC
```

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: This is already present i need to find out only rows with values 30 plus.

Comment: you have an issue finding a query because you are storing all the values for an application in a single comma separated field. Change your table to one row for each value of each application. you will have multiple rows for each application and it will be trivial to query as you want

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT payment_pattern, application
FROM yourTable
WHERE payment_pattern REGEXP '[[:<:]]([3-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)[[:>:]]';
```

*But*, you would do better to not store unnormalized CSV data in your tables.  Your query would be trivial if each number were stored in a separate record.

Here is a demo for the above regex:

### Demo

Here is a brief explanation of the above regex:

```
(
[3-9][0-9]             match 30 to 99
[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*  match 100 to 999, or this plus any other digit
)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.It Worked.If you could add a little explanation of what you did above that would be very helpful in future.

Comment: @user3225385 I have added a brief explanation of the regex.  A full explanation of how regex works would be out of scope for your question.